# How should I specify the path to my jtl files when I want to publish the performance report in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jmeter

In my Jenkins configuration, I have a build.xml file specified as post-build process. This build.xml file specifies the JMeter file (JMX) that I want to run and the location where I want to put the report file (jtl).

The location of my jtl files is `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\.jenkins\results\jtl\`.

I can see that the timestamp of the jtl file in this location matches the timestamp of my build. However, according to the Jenkins interface, under the category of "Publish Performance Test Result Report", I need to specify `**/*.jtl` as the JMeter file location.

I did that but my builds keep on failing because I keep getting a message saying `No JMeter files matching '**/*.jtl" have been found`.
I believe this path needs to relative to the workspace root path.
I have tried using relative path (i.e. `../../results/jtl/*.jtl`) and absolute path.
But they all give me saying no Jmeter files matching whatever the path is.

So, just exactly what am I supposed to put there for Jenkins to find my .jtl file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using `**/*.jtl` with no issues.

However, the location of the your jtl files is questionable.
Typically, they are found within the workspace of the job.

My workspace structure looks like

```
results/jtl/*.jtl
```

Comment: After adjusting the location of my jtl file, jenkins can now find my jtl file.  Thank you very much for your help!